# Rails: Simple-Form & Devise: mark email field of user model as required in forms automatically?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, validation, devise, simple-form

I wonder why the field `email` is not marked as a required field in Simple-Form, as when submitting it empty there is a validation error "can't be blank".

[image: screenshot]

It seems that the validation rules for the email field come from Devise, so they are available to the validation mechanism, but not to Simple-Form. Why's that?

I could simply add another `validates :email, presence: true` to my `User` model, but this seems overkill. Or I could add a `required: true` to the `f.input :email` method of Simple-Form, but this seems like overkill, too.

Here's the relevant part of my `User` model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,
         :confirmable, :lockable, authentication_keys: [:login]

  validates :name, presence: true
```

Do I have something configured incorrect/incomplete?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Simple Form's [README](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form):

> For performance reasons, this detection is skipped on validations that
>   make use of conditional options, such as :if and :unless.

And you can see that Devise will add validation with an `:if` in https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/models/validatable.rb

```
    base.class_eval do
      validates_presence_of   :email, if: :email_required?
      validates_uniqueness_of :email, allow_blank: true, if: :email_changed?
      validates_format_of     :email, with: email_regexp, allow_blank: true, if: :email_changed?

      validates_presence_of     :password, if: :password_required?
      validates_confirmation_of :password, if: :password_required?
      validates_length_of       :password, within: password_length, allow_blank: true
    end
```

So you have to mark the field as required in your views.

Answer (score 0):

If u submit it blank it will show ask u to fill in the field,
if you submit it a wrong email is will ask for a valid email.

So it check for blank first, if not blank then it checks if valid.

Your form is doing just fine.